# PHP Error: Drush\Application::setLogger(Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger) must be compatible in two given files | How to fix this error?

Tags: drush, composer

I was trying to setup a local environment of a website created on Acquia cloud platform. Everything was done properly including the database import. But now, when I execute drush commands, it gives me the following error.

> PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Drush\Application::setLogger(Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger) must be compatible with Psr\Log\LoggerAwareInterface::setLogger(Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger): void in C:\xampp\htdocs\pk-new\vendor\psr\log\Psr\Log\LoggerAwareTrait.php on line 22

I tried to rectify this by finding a solution online. The solution I found was to include :void in the function definition of the file throwing the error. After saving this, when I tried to run the drush commands it threw another error.

This time it was related to the $message variable not being compatible in two files. I tried to find the solution to this but then after fixing that it threw another error of the same type. I believe there is a right way to fix this without playing with the core files.

Is this a problem related to drush being globally installed? I am not too sure of that and also on how to go about it if that is the case.

I had done this type of an export in the past and it worked just fine, but now it is not. I feel that the compatibility of drush and php version might be causing problems.
The version I have are:

> Drush - 11.4.0
> PHP 8.1.14

Please let me know if there is a way to fix this issue. And if not, whether this issue will create problems while working on the website in the future.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I did check this post out. This is the solution that did not workout for me as mentioned in the my question. I did not understand this particular solution given in that post though: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/313250/109197

Comment: Execute `vendor/drush/drush/drush cr`, does the error persist? Add a sample command to your question. Is Drush Launcher involved?

Comment: No, the error did not appear when I executed ```vendor/drush/drush/drush cr```. But it does appear when I execute ```drush cr```. No, drush launcher is not involved as far as I know

Comment: Follow this answer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/313491/47547 and uninstall Drush globally. Run `which drush` to find the location of the globally installed Drush. Then you can install [Drush Launcher](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher) so that you don't need to type the path to the local Drush every time.